# Keep getting missing ";" before "." errors

Tags: c++

I have the header specification for a class here:

```
#ifndef FIXEDWINGAIRCRAFT_H
#define FIXEDWINGAIRCRAFT_H

#include <iostream>

class FixedWingAircraft
{
  private:
    struct Airframe
    {
        double weight;
    };
    struct Engine
    {
        double weight;
    double fuel;
    };
    struct Radio
    {
        bool state;
    double weight;
    };
    struct Pilot
    {
        int proficiency;
    double weight;
    };
    public:
    void setAirframe(double w)
    {
        Airframe.weight = w;
    }
    void setEngine(double w, double f)
    {
        Engine.weight = w;
    Engine.fuel = f;
    }
    void setRadio(bool s, double w)
    {
        Radio.state = s;
    Radio.weight = w;
    }
    void setPilot(int p, double w)
    {
        Pilot.proficiency = p;
    Pilot.weight = w;
    }
};
#endif
```

But when I try to compile, I get tons of syntax errors saying:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
```

I'm assuming these refer to the setter functions, but I don't see why that should be causing an issue. What am i missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Airframe.weight = w;` and all similar others are illegal. `Airframe` is a class, not an object. You're probably looking to have an object of that type as a member and set its properties.

You could replace

```
struct Airframe
{
    double weight;
};
```

with

```
struct Airframe
{
    double weight;
} airframe;
```

This would give you a member of that type in `FixedWingAircraft` which you can access with `airframe`.

Comment: @bobdolan: Right, `Airframe` is a _type_, not an object.

Answer (score 4):

`Airframe, Raid, Pilot, Engine` are `struct` type, you should use an instance/object of them to access their members. For example:

```
Airframe a;
a.weight  = w;
```